# Why do I have so many filesystems?

Tags: 16.04, filesystem, storage

Here is my output after running `df -h --total`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           784M  9.9M  774M   2% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p3  216G  182G   24G  89% /
tmpfs           3.9G   33M  3.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p1  496M   28M  469M   6% /boot/efi
cgmfs           100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs           784M     0  784M   0% /run/user/0
tmpfs           784M  104K  783M   1% /run/user/1001
/dev/mmcblk0p1   60G  1.4G   59G   3% /media/joe/3666-6537
total           290G  183G   96G  66% -
```

I have a lot of photos and videos on this drive, which are clearly all being kept in `/dev/nvme0n1p3`. I've recently cleared some space, but certainly not `96G` worth (The total `Avail`). Before I did cleanup (of around `20G`, which agrees with the `Avail` amount on `/dev/nvme0n1p3`), I was not able to export from photo editing applications or render any videos, having been given warnings bout my disk being full. Obviously, this was only the `/dev/nvme0n1p3` filesystem that was full.

So why do I have so much storage in these other `dev` and `tmpfs` partitions (is partition the right word here?) that seems to being going unused? I assume that the `tmp` directories fill up with junk when the system is in heavy use? And what is `/dev/mmcblk0p1`, which is using hardly any of it's allotted `60G` of storage?

Comment: @user68186 Ah, yes, my mistake. That's an SD card. Thanks

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1001089/edit) your question to reflect this new information.